# Strange variable initialization error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a strange problem with variable initialization.

There is following code:

```
public void test()
    {
        StringBuilder buf;

        org.junit.Assert.assertFalse((buf = new StringBuilder("qwe3")).toString().isEmpty());
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("", buf.toString()); // The local variable buf may not have been initialized
    }
```

What??? Variable is initialized, what is wrong?

also when I change `org.junit.Assert.assertFalse` to my own local method error disappears.

```
private static void assertFalse(final boolean o) throws Exception
    {

    }
```

I am using jdk 1.7.0_51 if that matters. Class code is [here](http://pastebin.com/35c6wtN4)

Comment: That's the *exact* code, copied and pasted verbatim? Do you have another machine you can try to reproduce it on? Anything interesting in the surrounding code? (If you could produce a short but complete example we can just compile for ourselves verbatim, that would help.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I reproduced it, it just needs a JUnit dependency.

Comment: @JonSkeet, added link to pastebin

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Are you using 1.7.0_51 as well? Just wondering what the exact requirements are...

Comment: Actually irrelevant, compiling with Eclipse. But good point, let's see javac...

Comment: @JonSkeet And... it compiles with `javac`! A bug in Eclipse compiler. Java version is 1.7.0_40.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Interesting - it's compiling fine in Eclipse for me, but I'll try to reproduce on another computer. I haven't tried with javac yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet Kepler SR1? BTW I'm using Eclipse's own JUnit 4 dependency (the Library feature).

Comment: Okay, now I've managed to reproduce it. Does look like an Eclipse bug. I wonder whether it's Eclipse trying to optimize away code that it knows will succeed, but forgetting about side-effects...

Comment: In my opinion, Java warns you because your initialisation is done in a test. For example, if you change your statement to <code>org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(false && (buf = new StringBuilder("qwe3")).toString().isEmpty());</code> your local variable will actually NOT be initialized because false && anything is always false and Java won't even try to evaluate the second part of your expression. It could explain the warning you have maybe.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm reproducing with my own `package org.junit;

public class Assert {

  public static void assertFalse(boolean b) {}

  public static void assertEquals(String s1, String s2) {}
}`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Right - but change `Assert` to `Assert2` and all is well. Fascinating. Definitely an Eclipse bug.

Comment: @Julien: The code is perfectly valid code. Eclipse isn't producing a warning, it's producing an *error*, and doing so is broken. The variable *is* definitely assigned according to Java language rules. This is Eclipse trying to be clever about JUnit, and failing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Excellent narrowing down! So they have a special case in there, and it is based on the fully-qualified method name, including the method signature.

Comment: @JonSkeet BTW checked the bytecode, they don't eliminate any of the code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Interesting. There's definitely code analysis going on, in that if you have `assertNull((buf = new StringBuilder());` instead of the `assertFalse`, then there are no errors but a warning on the `assertEquals` to say it's dead code...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, there appears to be code analysis done in an earlier step before bytecode generation. I can see the good intentions paving the road to this particular hell :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I know it's valid. What I meant is that Eclipse might be mistaking because of the boolean evaluation that is made at the same time of your local variable's init. It's obviously a lack of cleverness of Eclipse.

Comment: @Julien It is actually the *excess* of cleverness gone wrong. The error in question, `variable may not have been initialized`, is precisely governed by the rules of the Java Language Specification (*definite assignment*) and it is not down to any compiler's *cleverness*, but to its *compliance with the specification*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Note: this is now reported as [Eclipse JDT Bug 426443](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426443).

I have trimmed your issue down to an MCVE:

```
package org.junit;
public class Assert {
  public static void assertTrue(boolean b) {}
}

package test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
public class Test {
  void test() {
    int i;
    assertTrue((i = 1) == 1);
    assertTrue(i == 1);
  }
}
```

Only when compiling with Eclipse Kepler SR1 do I get your exact error; compiling with `javac` does not reproduce it.

In addition, changing `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(boolean b)` to a slightly different:

- package name;
- class name;
- method name;
- method signature

the error disappears. `assertFalse` has the same problem and probably other methods in the real `Assert` class.

Conclusion: the bug is in the Eclipse compiler.